# Value of variable changes when used outside of the function it is assigned in

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

I have created a function which gets the directory path of a file as follows:

```
def discoverLocation(self):
    self.txtBox.insert(1.0, askdirectory())
    if(self.txtBox.get(1.0) != 0):
        global path
        path = self.txtBox.get(1.0,END)
        print "path is "  + path
```

The output of this function works as intended, meaning outputting "path is 'directory of file'"

However when I use this 'path' variable from outside this function, the variable seems to change.

This is the code:

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    path = StringVar()
    print path


    dirs = os.listdir(path)
    for file in dirs:
        totalFiles += 1
```

The value of path over here is not the same path as before, it is displaying the name 'PY_VAR0'.

I want to use the same value given from the discoverLocation(self) method in the def_init_(self,parent) method.

Comment: Where do you define the variable path globaly?

Comment: I defined it in the _init_ function 
path = StringVar()

Comment: You assign `path = StringVar()`. Of course it's not going to be the same thing you assigned it earlier; it's going to be a `StringVar`! Also, you forgot to declare it `global` in `__init__`, but just fixing that isn't going to be enough to fix your bigger problems.

Comment: Are both functions in the same class? If so, why don't you save it as class attribute?

Comment: Yes they are both in the same class, you mean to declare the path as a StringVar() outside of both functions ?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have missed the fundamental point of classes: they store information in their instance attributes. You don't want to create a global variable, you want to create an instance attribute. You do that by referring to it via `self`.

So, in `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    self.path = StringVar()
```

and you can now refer to `self.path` in `discoverLocation`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do 2 things:

1. Return the value of path from your `discoverLocation`, rather than trying to make it global e.g.:

   ```
   class MyClass(object):
       def discoverLocation(self):
           self.txtBox.insert(1.0, askdirectory())
           if(self.txtBox.get(1.0) != 0):
               path = self.txtBox.get(1.0,END)
               print "path is "  + path
               return path
           return None
   ```
2. Use that path in the main function e.g.:

   ```
   def __init__(self, parent):
       path = self.discoverLocation()
       print path
       dirs = os.listdir(path)
       for file in dirs:
          totalFiles += 1
   ```

You'll also need to decide what to do if the path isn't found - e.g. if `discoverLocation()` returns `None`

Comment: I had tried to do something like that and got the error global name 'DiscoverLocation' is not defined

Comment: you need to use `self.discoverLocation()` if it's in the same class as `__init__()`